# What is the best way to implement a generic range as a function argument in Java?

Tags: java

I have a function that needs a range as an argument. The domain is [0-100] and it includes 0 and 100. The range argument could for example be:

`[1-8, 18, 20-88, 90-92]`

or

`[1, 10-30]`

Ranges do not overlap. I am interested in the mechanism - how best to pass a range argument? Array? or use variable argument?

Comment: I don't see a way to distinguish a pair of numbers vs. a range.  I think you'll need to create a special Range class to hold the ranges.

Comment: `func(1,-8, 18, 20,-88, 90,-92)`  HA!

Answer (score 5):

Use a list of Range objects:

```
class Range
{
    int low;
    int high;

    Range(int low, int high)
    {
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }
}

List<Range> rangeArray = new ArrayList<Range>();
```

then assign ranges like this:

```
rangeArray.add(new Range(1,8));
rangeArray.add(new Range(18,18));
rangeArray.add(new Range(20,88));
rangeArray.add(new Range(90,92));
```

Comment: You could of course just add the ranges as Integer objects in an ArrayList<Integer>, i.e. alternating lower and upper range. I preferred to show an IMHO "elegant" solution, that is easier to understand. It is important that code is readable. The more it is readable, the less bugs there will be, and the easier it is to change the code later.

Answer (score 1):

Have a static method `r()` that creates a range in some representation

```
func( r(1,8), r(18), r(20,88), r(90,92) )
```

Or use method chaining to create a list of ranges

```
func( Range.r(1,8).r(18).r(20,88).r(90,92) )
```

Or, as my joke comment

```
func(1,-8, 18, 20,-88, 90,-92)
```

Or, use `100*x+y` to represent `(x,y)`

```
func( 1_08, 18, 20_88, 90_92 );
```